# Why set "private" python attribute from *outside* the class?

Tags: python, django

Reading the Django source code I came upon [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/loader_tags.py#L173) function. It's the implementation for the [block](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#block) tag.

What interests me is that they're setting a variable with two leading underscores (`__loaded_blocks`) from *outside* the `parser` class instance (parser is an instance of the [Parser class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/base.py#L233)). A quick grep in the Django source code shows that the string `loaded_blocks` occurs only here.

Now I've never considered this use of the python name-mangling feature before, but this will in effect hide the `__loaded_blocks` attribute of `parser` from itself! To read this attribute from a `parser` method you have to resort to `getattr(self, "__loaded_blocks")`.

Am I right in thinking this is just an unintended and unused side effect of the chosen attribute name? Or is there a deeper purpose to this?

**In general, why would you want to do such a thing?**

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm fully aware that as long as you don't try to access the `__loaded_blocks` attribute from a method of `parser`, it will work just like any other attribute, and that it is in fact *not* a mangled attribute.

Comment: No purpose, DJango just has ugly code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Name mangling will take place when you add a property prefixed with `__` to an instance

from the [docs](http://cpython_sandbox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/expressions.html):

> Private name mangling: When an identifier that textually occurs in a
>   class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and
>   does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private
>   name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form
>   before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the
>   class name in front of the name, with leading underscores removed, and
>   a single underscore inserted in front of the class name. For example,
>   the identifier __spam occurring in a class named Ham will be
>   transformed to *Ham*_spam. This transformation is independent of the
>   syntactical context in which the identifier is used. If the
>   transformed name is extremely long (longer than 255 characters),
>   implementation defined truncation may happen. If the class name
>   consists only of underscores, no transformation is done.

```
class Test:
  pass

test = Test()
test.__hello = 'hii'    
test.__hello  # hiii
```

Although the name is not mangled it still marks this as "private" to the consumer of the code

Comment: Oh, I realize this. But if you created a method in `Test` that printed the `__hello` attribute after it was set, it would not be able to, because it would in fact try to print the `_Test__hello` attribute. As I said, such a method would have to use `getattr` to print the externally set `__hello` attribute.

Comment: @lazyr oo yes i see what you are saying now! they aren't reading it from a method and if they did i bet they wouldn't have created a variable with double underscores...